# Is there any Symfony CodeSniffer ruleset

Tags: php, symfony, phpcodesniffer

I've been trying to use PHP_CodeSniffer on Symfony projects but it usually throws warnings that are not usually follow by the Symfony community (Like commenting parameter tags or not grouping parameters and returns in function docs)

I was wondering if there is any official or unofficial but well-maintained ruleset for Symfony

I found this one:
https://github.com/djoos/Symfony2-coding-standard
Looks good but it hasn't been updated for a while now

Comment: the mentioned one is the only one I am aware of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) documentation is in http://cs.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: CS Fixer is the one!! +1

Comment: CodeSniffer and PHP-CS (coding standards) are not the same thing.

Comment: PHPCS is short for PHP Code Sniffer, Coding standards isn't abbreviated to PHP-CS as far as I know

Comment: The readme for the project calls it 'PHP Coding Standards Fixer'. As ironchicken says, CodeSniffer and PCP-CS are different things.

Comment: This doesn't tell anyone how to use it for *Symfony* and the tool of course doesn't default to Symfony's configuration